# No Errors in Logs, but SolrCore Initialization Failure?

Tags: tomcat, solr

I am faced to a very annoying SolR-Installation on my Debian 7 Server...
Since last year and solr version 3.x - there were obviously some changes that come now in solr 4.x that makes life harder ^^ at least, when setting apache-tomcat up with solr.

I use solr in combination with typo3cores. I set up the whole server in a structure like:

> /opt/solr-tomcat/ 
>   -> solr/ 
>   -> tomcat/

Everthingy seems to work and cores that I define in solr/solr.xml are being set up correctly - as the log's show.

Anyway, opening LYNX on localhost:8080/solr brings up errors and the page shows up like this:

> Apache SOLR
>
> **SolrCore Initialization Failures**
>
> Please check your logs for more information
>
> ```
>  * Dashboard
>  * Logging
>       + Level
>  * Cloud
>       + Tree
>       + Graph
>       + Graph (Radial)
>       + Dump
>  * Core Admin
>  * Java Properties
>  * Thread Dump
> ```
>
> No cores available Go and create one
>
> ```
>  * Documentation
>  * Issue Tracker
>  * IRC Channel
>  * Community forum
>  * Solr Query Syntax
> ```
>
> Connection lost …

I know that you could certainly not provide a solution right away, but an idea about where to look and what to check (xml files, global variables, etc) would be awesome - as theres no hint in catalina.out or solr.log - neither in message or syslog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
With the new version of solr-tomcat Lynx doesn't work anymore. With any other graphical browser ist works - just that on webservers theres usually nothing else ^^